# php show array items with pagination

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array index $aawp_table['products'] . I did var_dump of the index below. the output showing how the columns should show up. like there have custom text index and others

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
["status"]=>
bool(true)
["asin"]=>
string(10) "B00EJ9CQKA"
["rows"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "custom_text"
    ["values"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["custom_text"]=>
      string(15) "Top of the List"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "thumb"
    ["values"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "custom_text"
    ["values"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["custom_text"]=>
      string(16) "Work Sharp Knife"
    }
  }
 }
 ["highlight"]=>
bool(false)
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
["status"]=>
bool(true)
["asin"]=>
string(10) "B0018RSEMU"
["rows"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "custom_text"
    ["values"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["custom_text"]=>
      string(18) "Bottom of the list"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "thumb"
    ["values"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(11) "custom_text"
    ["values"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["custom_text"]=>
      string(11) "Sharp Knife"
      }
    }
  }
 ["highlight"]=>
  bool(false)
 }
```

}

I want the array output with pagination like 1 item per page. The table structure should be like below

```
 Pick Name           Top of the List       Bottom of the list
 ============================================================
 Preview             thumb                 thumb
 ============================================================
 Title               Work Sharp Knife      Sharp Knife
 ============================================================
```

the first column should be constant. Below are code for table showing up

```
<div id="aawp-tb-<?php echo $aawp_table['id']; ?>">

  
    <div class="aawp-tb aawp-tb--desktop aawp-tb--cols-<?php echo ( sizeof( $aawp_table['products'] ) + 1 ); ?><?php aawp_the_table_customization_classes( 'aawp-tb' ); ?>">

        <?php foreach ( $aawp_table['rows'] as $table_row_id => $table_row ) : ?>

            <?php if ( ! $table_row['status'] )
                continue; ?>

            <div class="aawp-tb__row<?php if ( $table_row['highlight'] ) echo ' aawp-tb__row--highlight'; ?>">

                <div class="aawp-tb__head">
                    <?php echo ( isset( $table_row['label'] ) ) ? $table_row['label'] : ''; ?>
                </div>

                <?php foreach ( $aawp_table['products'] as $table_product_id => $table_product ) : ?>

                    <?php if ( empty ( $table_product['asin'] ) )
                        continue; ?>

                    <?php if ( $table_product['rows'][$table_row_id] ) : ?>

                        <div class="aawp-tb-product-<?php echo $table_product_id; ?> <?php aawp_the_table_product_data_classes( 'aawp-tb__data', $table_row_id, $table_product_id ); ?><?php if ( $table_product['highlight'] ) echo ' aawp-tb__data--highlight'; ?>">
                            <?php aawp_the_table_product_highlight_ribbon( $table_product_id, $table_row_id ); ?>
                            <?php aawp_the_table_product_data( $table_row_id, $table_product_id ); ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show the php codes you have written (show us your codes first)

Comment: I have added the code please check

Comment: it looks like you would like to present values for each entry in columns rather than rows, isn't it? so the left most column is the table heading and all other rows are presenting data? And I guess 'thumb' will have a value for some thumbnails?